# matplotlib dependency: kernel32.dll

Tags: matplotlib, pythonxy

I have a question that is very similar to [Matplotlib on Windows - dependency unresolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383695/matplotlib-on-windows-dependency-unresolved), but I have a conflict with c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll.

Backstory: with pythonxy, on
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`
I get:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py", line 58, in 
<module>
from matplotlib import ft2font
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

From Dependency Walker on ft2font.pyd,
[I see that there is a problem with kernel32.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1bJg.png). Per my googling, kernel32.dll is pretty important and, unlike (my reading of) the linked post to a comparable problem, c:\python27\dlls\ doesn't have an alternate version of kernel32.dll for python to use instead. Thus, I'm hesitant to delete/rename kernel32.dll in c:\win.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT: switched to Anaconda and the problem went away. Still curious to why this step was necessary.**

Comment: First of all a solution to a problem with python cannot be to change any windows dll. That said, you may have a version conflict, i.e. the python version does not match the operating system. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling python? If this is a problem with pythonxy, have you considered trying a different distribution like winpython or anaconda?

Comment: Thanks for your response. After a few attempts at uninstalling and reinstalling Python (1x) and Pythonxy (2x), I uninstalled and switched to Anaconda: so far, so good.